# Print proper log file from a terminal session

Tags: scripting, terminal, logs

I am trying to log a terminal with the

```
ssh user@ip | tee -a test.log
```

command. But, when I push backspace it prints in the log like:

```
pwe[J[J[Jexit
```

(for example). Is there any specific option that i can erase the backspace, etc chars and write only what I type in the end?

Comment: I get a `\b` (backspace) character, the output is not too surprising, it has a lot of control characters in it, to control the terminal, including `\n` already being converted to `\r\n`. There must be a way to turn off this filter.

Comment: Ok, but how i avoid all these unnecessary prints in my log file?

Comment: There is the `-T` option to `ssh`, but this in intended for non interactive mode. You will not see any prompts, and the log will only contain strict output. e.g. `echo hello` will log `hello`.

Comment: When I do `cat test.log` it looks fine. But if in inspect the file with `od` I see the various control characters. (this will be a problem if you want to put the data through filters).

Comment: That's exactly my point. i want to process data afterwards. So, any suggestions?

Comment: There is the script command, that is for doing logging, but must be run on the other end (so the file will be on the other machine).

Comment: I know that, i want the output file in my machine though, because i want to parse the file and this happens only with the >> or | tee commands. The script command appears its output after i exit the terminal to my machine.

Comment: These questions are similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273817/removing-control-special-characters-from-log-file OR http://superuser.com/questions/236930/how-to-clean-up-output-of-linux-script-command though they don't have good answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42479/discussion-between-richard-and-kostas).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `script` instead of `| tee ..`. `script` is tool for capturing user's output, so no need to invent anything new and I believe this should be resolved there.

To use `script` for ssh only you can use:

```
script -c "ssh ip@host" your.log
```

or create (a stupid) function:

```
function sssh() { script -c "ssh $1" $2 }
sssh ip@host your.log
```

Comment: the problem with script is that it doesn't update "live" like | tee command. And it writes the result after you close the terminal. I want to see the result live. But still, the problem remains with script command. Already tested it.